# QueryTables error

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, excel-2007

I have the following VBA code inside an Excel macro:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:=ConnStr, _
    Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), _
    Sql:=SqlStr)
        .Refresh
End With
```

And yet I am getting the error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error." The debugger points to this code as the source of error.

Assuming that my ConnStr and SqlStr are correct, why am I getting this error? I am using Excel 2007 and I am querying an Oracle database.

Comment: That part of your code looks OK (again, assuming ConnStr and SqlStr are syntactically correct). That error message is unfortunately very generic. I would check the surrounding code to make sure that it contains no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, Adam. I managed to fix the problem. The problem was with my Connection and SQL strings. I needed to prepend "ODBC" to my conn string, and then I needed to add some spaces to my SQL string. I forget which caused the error.